# Android code coverage per pull request in SonarQube

Tags: android, sonarqube, automated-tests, android-testing, jacoco

Is there a way to do test coverage checks on a per pull-request basis?

I.e. I want each pull request to have 90% coverage itself.

Comment: This is not currently supported, but coming soon. You can track it here: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1118

Answer (score 0):

as of SonarQube 7.4 looks like they started offering something similar to what your looking for https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-7-4/